# Real Time data logging design Approach?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a real time trace logging application in wpf.I am reading logged data from a UDP port and converting it in terms of my modal class.The thing i am worried is, consider if the user keeps the application open for a long period of time,the application will be using a large amount of memory.I display the log information in a scrollable list,so the user has the provision to scroll up to and get to a previous log.I'm looking for a  design approach so that i can deliver the best results with the optimal use of memory.So which is the best design approach for this kind of application ?

Answer (score 1):

"Real Time" mean as soon as data is available Application should pick up it and display. No other way.

- You can consider something like cleanup of the already previewed logging information if this is appropriate from user perspectives and load historical data on demand.
- Also one of the possible solutions is to optimize `LogInformation`data model so entities which you are displaying would require less memory, this could be significant improvement considering that a lot of entries are displayed and each single saved byte may result in MegaBytes of saved memory, so please share some code of entities which are bound to UI and indicate which fields/properties really need to be displayed to end user
- For some kind of data you can implement [Lazy Loading](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) and request data from DB/file system on demand. For instance when an user opening Details form for a particular LogInfo entry in the UI list you are requesting advanced information like full description and so on, so you do not need to keep it always in memory whilst user do not request it by opening "More Details" form
- If DB calls is high cost for your Applicaiton you can store some information on the file system in serialized format and load it On Demand in Lazy Loading manner.

Really it is hard to suggest something concrete without of knowledge of the Use Cases and standard workflows. So please provide more details how this applicaiton is used by an user so more ideas coudl come in.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that might work is to add a "listener"  that would see if the program was altered, or after lets say 5 minutes of seeming idle a popup would ask if you want to continue. It would then reconnect once the user clicks "ok"

Would that work? I am assuming that the memory use is on the log server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your have two much data to display. You can use UI Virtualization. **VirtualizingStackPanel** can do what you want by not creating UI elements for all your log lines untill the user scrolls to it. A example would be too long for stackoverflow. There are plenty of examples on the web.

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338

On the other hand if you are memory requirements are too high just because there is too much log data. Consider writing it to a database on disk.

Comment: Data dislay is ok.As you said the VirtualizingStackPanel can do the work.But i iam concerned about the memory used by too much objects

Comment: You bind your VirtualizingStackPanel to a DataSource that is read from the database on demand.

Comment: for your model objects you can use WeakReferences